# How to transform rows to columns in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column like this:

```
  values
0  3.1
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  4.3
```

And I want to transform the rows to columns and attach the column names
like this:

```
A     B    C    D
3.1  2.0  3.0  4.3
```

How do I do this in python?

Comment: Transpose: `df.T` + rename

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.T
df.columns = list("ABCD")
```